# HTTP request in case of didEnterRegion, didExitRegion

Tags: ios, objective-c, locationmanager, ibeacon

I am a little bit confused about this question.

Somewhere I read, it is not allowed by Apple to make network requests, when an app not in the foreground. Is also the case, when app is woken up by `locationManager` events?

What I'd like to: define a Beacon region, handle `locationManager:didEnterRegion:` and `locationManager:didExitRegion:` to call my simple web service methods. It should be done even if the app is not active and woken up by location manager.

Technically it is easy to implement - basically, I have already made it - but I don't know if it is allowed by Apple, and would take app review successfully.

Thanks!

Comment: Based off a quick skim of the [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) I didn't see anything specifically about this, but I'm not sure if it's one of their "unwritten rules" or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed.  It is a common technique, and I have several apps in the AppStore that do this.  The [Beacon Scavenger Hunt](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/beacon-scavenger-hunt/id821092269?mt=8), for example, sends stats back to our server when participants use the iOS app to find beacon targets in the hunt.

When you detect a beacon in the background, however, you only have about 5 seconds of running time from iOS.  Take care that your server responds quickly enough.   This small time window is the way Apple enforces that people don't abuse this.

Comment: I haven't been able to get my HTTP call to Twilio to send yet, I know didEnterRegion is firing as I'm pushing a local notification to the device. I've tried turning on UIBackgroundMode in the plist to no avail, I think that only allows background calls from certain delegate responses. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know for sure that Twilio doesn't get the message?  I would set up your own web service endpoint, point to that and see if it is getting called.  You could use something like this for testing:  http://postcatcher.in